# Command to open transparent terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

Sometimes I need to open transparent terminal,but I don't want to  change the terminal setting.And if I know the command I can set a shortkey/hotkey using this command.

Is there any command to open transparent terminal?

Comment: You can install [Guake](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/guake/). It has adjustable transparency, and its standard hotkey is F12.

Comment: +1 for Guake. That option is in Preferences, Appearence Tab. Great for nostalgic Quake 3 players too :'(

Comment: You can create multiple profiles, make one of them transparent, and ask to open gnome-terminal with that profile.

Comment: Thank you egmont.Your solution is easy.It is work for me.But I have to use mouse to change profile(switch another profile).It is better if there is shortkey.

Comment: You can open a new terminal from the command line with a specific profile, i.e. `gnome-terminal --profile WhateverName`. If you wish to change the profile later on, indeed you have to use the mouse.